# Где физически находится pool SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pool

По поиску наткнулся на то, что у SQLAlchemy есть пул потоков: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html
Настраивается он просто, указав параметры в create_engine.

У меня вопрос, где физически храниться этот пул? В каждой запущенной процессе питона (я так понимаю в каждом wsgi) свой пул? Или как-то по другому? Как вообще это устроенно в питоне?

Comment: Что-то вы криво как-то вопрос поменяли ))

Comment: @GixWay, не нужно вандализировать вопрос.

Comment: Система не дает удалить мое сообщение. Как иначе?

Comment: @GixWay А зачем вы его удаляете? Этот сайт специально хранит вопросы и ответы, чтобы не надо было каждый раз на одно и то же отвечать

Comment: Мне не понравился этот сайт и я хочу удалить свои данные.

Comment: @GixWay это будет, как минимум, некрасиво по отношению к тем, кто старался вам помочь.

Answer (score 4):

Не потоков, соединений с базой. Да, у каждого процесса пул свой. Это обычный *callable*, возвращающийся соединение из управляемой им коллекции. То есть в предельно простом случае это может быть просто функция, возвращающая новое соединение. Реальные пулы - это классы, хранящие внутри себя коллекции свободных и выданных подключений, ведущие статистику по времени жизни соединений, проверяющие их активность, закрывающие и открывающие их при необходимости.